# Double with ksoap2 on Android?

Tags: java, android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

How do I add a double property to a ksoap2 request?

```
request.addProperty("doubleProperty", 1.0);
```

There are no nice and clear answers on the web.

Answer (score 3):

In order to send the double value as a request parameter you need to use Marshaling concept.

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/implementing-ksoap-marshal-interface.html)

I also found [this](http://android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/167-using-ksoap2-for-android-soap-web-service) to be useful.

Try googling for more info on the Marshaling concept

All the best

Cheers